# When we log in to the App, we are taken to the Home Screen. we have not visible Drawer navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation

```
    import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
    import React from 'react';
    import Reg_form from './Frontend/Components/RegForm';
    import Login_form from './Frontend/Components/Signin';
    import ForgotPassword from './Frontend/Components/ForgotPassword';
    import { ApplicationProvider, Layout, Text } from '@ui-kitten/components';
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
    import {
      createDrawerNavigator,
      DrawerContentScrollView,
      DrawerItemList,
      DrawerItem,
    } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
    import ChangePassword from './Frontend/Components/ChangePassword';
    import VerifyOTP from './Frontend/Components/VerifyOTP';
    import Home from './Frontend/Components/Home Screen';
    import Profile from './Frontend/Components/Profile';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons'
    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    
    const CustomDrawer = props => {
    
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
            <View
              style={{
                alignSelf: "center",
                padding: 20,
    
              }}
            >
              <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold" }}> App</Text>
              </View>
    
            </View>
            <DrawerItemList {...props} />
            <LogoutButton iconName="sign-out" color="black" />
          </DrawerContentScrollView>
    
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    
    
    function DrawerRoutes() {
    
    
      return (
    
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
    
          drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
        >
    
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home}
    
            options={{
              headerShown: true,
              
              title: 'Home',
              drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
                <Icon
                  name="home"
                  size={size}
                  color='black'
    
                />
    
              )
            }}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}
    
            options={{
              headerShown: true,
              title: 'Profile',
              drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
                <Icon
                  name="user"
                  size={size}
                  color='black'
    
                />
    
              )
            }}
          />
        
    
    
    
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      );
    }
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}> 
        
        <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={Reg_form} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="Log In" component={Login_form}/>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Forgot" component={ForgotPassword}/>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Password" component={ChangePassword}/>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Verification" component={VerifyOTP}/>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="DrawerRoutes" component={DrawerRoutes}/>
                 
      </Stack.Navigator>
      
      </NavigationContainer>
        
      </ApplicationProvider>
      );
    }
```

*Error: When we log in to the App, we are taken to the Home Screen. However, we cannot see the Drawer navigation. The drawer navigation is hidden. Please go through this again. The HeaderShown option is set to true. we have updated the Home screen to show the drawer navigation menu. We have done this by setting the headerShown property to true. This will ensure that the drawer navigation menu is always visible when the Home screen is rendered but Drawer navigation is not visible on the Home Screen.

Comment: After login, you should navigate to "DrawerRoutes" instead of "Home", since your home page is included in drawer navigator already.